# Redis: How do I calculate time differences in a sorted list time-series?

Tags: redis, lua, time-series

I'm trying to calculate the response times between messages stored in Redis. But I have no clue how to do this.

First I have to store the time-stream of chat_messages like this

```
ZADD conversation:CONVERSATION_ID:chat_messages TIMESTAMP CHAT_MESSAGE_ID
ZADD conversation:9:chat_messages 1511533205001 2583
ZADD conversation:9:chat_messages 1511533207057 732016
```

Afterward, I need the application to be able to calculate the time difference between timestamps using Redis because I need the extra speed of doing it without another (potentially slower) technology.

Is there a way of achieving this using plain Redis or Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp you are using seems to be in milliseconds, so you only need to substract and convert to your desired units.

You can get the score using [`ZSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zscore) for each message. Or use one of the ZRANGE methods to get multiple messages at once: [`ZRANGEBYSCORE ... WITHSCORES`](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore).

You can use a Lua script to get the time difference:

```
local t1 = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
local t2 = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[2])
return tonumber(t2) - tonumber(t1)
```

Here the full EVAL command:

```
EVAL "local t1 = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) local t2 = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[2]) return tonumber(t2) - tonumber(t1)" 1 conversation:9:chat_messages 2583 732016
```